# How to kill previous Python process when rebuilding a program in Sublime

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, python-idle

I used to work in IDLE. There, if I reran a program it automatically kills the previous instances of the program.

But recently I shifted to Sublime. If I rerun the same program here, all the previous instances do not die and keep on running.

Can any one provide a method so that when I rebuild a program the previous instances automatically die.

Answer (score 1):

If a build is still running, simply select **`Tools → Cancel Build`** and it will be killed. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Break</kbd> as a keyboard shortcut.